# Unable to fetch the value of an element in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor, ui-automation, gettext, getattribute

For one of my protractor script. I want to fetch the value of an element.

Here is the DOM setup:

```
<h5 class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="editor.special.stock_number !== ''">
<b>Stock Number:</b>
 72850
</h5>
```

I want to fetch the value of **Stock Number:**

I tried using **getText**, but it just printed out the **Stock Number:**

```
this.get_stock_number = () => {
        let stockNumber = stock_number.getText();
        stockNumber.then((text) => {
            console.log("Stock Number is: " + text);
        });
    };
```

I also tried using **getAttribute** but it is returning null:

```
this.get_stock_number = () => {
        let stockNumber = stock_number.getAttribute('Stock Number:');
        stockNumber.then((text) => {
            console.log("Stock Number is: " + text);
        });
    };
```

I really need this thing to be sorted out. I am kind of stuck here. 
Any help will be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I usually try printing out the DOM element on console.log to see what is there... in your case console.log(stock_number)

Comment: @amitesh - Can you show code how you are finding this element stock_number ?

Comment: @AIqbal How can I just print the stock number in the console. Can you explain it a little bit more

Comment: @AmitJain You want me to show you the xpath ??

Comment: @AmitJain locators.findByXpath("//*[@id='container']//*[contains(text(),'Stock Number:')]");

Comment: you can console.log any DOM element... try console.log($('body'))... traverse and print out the exact place where you are struggling to see the value/text

Comment: with <h5 class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-if="editor.special.stock_number !== ''"><b>Stock Number:</b><span>72850 </span></h5> go to Chrome's console and do console.log($('span')[0].innerText);

Comment: @AIqbal I understood the way which you mentioned. But the solution given by "Infern0" looks more appropriate for me. Thanks for looking into the problem and giving your time to answer it. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

- Locate the h5 element with the whole text and extract it

> h5element.getText()

so it can return Ex:

> `<b>Stock Number:</b>    72850`

- After that just extract the number from the string with regex

> ```
> let text = `<b>dsadsad</b> 320301`;
> let numberPattern = /\d+/g;
> let results = text.match(numberPattern);
> if (results != null) {
>     let number = results[0];
>     console.log(number);
> }
> ```

Comment: The regexp is not working. I tried a few other regexp but they also didn't work.

Comment: i have run the example string that you get, mentioned above and the result is number. also you can verify the regex here: https://regex101.com/